# "Unauthorized request" frequently happen with LinkedIn API

Tags: rest, api, linkedin-api

I'm using the LinkedIn API (rest API with PHP) and a few days after I refresh the access token it starts returning this error:

```
{

    "errorCode":0,
    "message":"Unauthorized request",
    "requestId":"9VM1NZAEBX",
    "status":403,
    "timestamp":1539345244158

}
```

And I need to refresh it again, to make it work.

**EDIT:**

Here is the API call I am doing, it just fails few days after get the new token, but the TTL is 2 months (this time it failed 3 days after the gettting the new token, the exacly same request worked before and works after gettting a new token):

POST - https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/5040237/shares?format=json

```
{

    "visibility":{

        "code":"anyone"

    },

    "comment":"Ainda não segue a blink-iT no Youtube? Está a perder várias dicas como esta⤵ em que explicamos como criar produtos, variantes, referências cruzadas e também como definir unidades de medida no NAV. Subscreva o nosso canal  https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0COxR5KPo0At-mEkZQYyRA ",

    "content":{

        "submitted-url":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LcwXAf0d2tg",

        "submitted-image-url":"https://arq.swonkie.com/php/image.php?this=84df3c5d9174b56828e33c0206d6c2cf.jpg",

        "title":"NAV2017 - Como criar Produtos",

        "description":"FastTrack - Soluções de Negócio, na Cloud. Experimente grátis. ERP (Dynamics NAV), CRM (Dynamics 365), BI (Power BI) e Produtividade e Colaboração (Office 36..."

    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you requesting this API access? Show us your PHP code.

Comment: that is because you havent given the access token properly..

Comment: When you refresh your token have a look at the duration or TTL for the token. If your refresh problem is constant, eveything points to your token expiration

Comment: @Sanguinary this has nothng to do with php code

Comment: @Auris I will check that, I have a few test accounts, and this only happen in 2, the other 4 are working fine and when the token expires on those 4 it returns the message: "Expired access token", not the above one.
Based on LinkedIn API documentation (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/error-handling), the code 403 seems like an Access Denied error, but the cases it list for analyse, are ok from my side and if some of them were wrong it shouldn't work with any account.

Comment: @Auris sorry for the delay, I checked the token duration, and it is about 2 months until expiration, but it only worked for 2 days and the above error showed up (403 - Access Denied).

Answer (score 0):

So the 403 forbidden error , accrues when you try to access a V2 API call. these api calls are restricted to partners of linkedin. you can become a linkedin partner by applying for one of the partnership programs.

> Partnering with LinkedIn provides you with additional API functionality & data access, increased call limits & dedicated support. Read more about our various Partner Programs and use cases and see if one is a match for your app. Applications are only accepted when we feel that they're providing value to members, developers and LinkedIn.

**Linkedin link to partnership programs:**
https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs

**NOTE:**

keep in mind that requesting a partnership can take up to 1-2 months.

---

the V1 API calls are open for use for the people without a partnership program.

**EDIT:**

i found some additional information about the refreshing of tokens :

> LinkedIn has introduced Refresh Tokens with OAuth 2.0.  This feature is currently available for a limited set of partners. It will be made GA in the near future.

**Linkedin Refresh Tokens:**
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/Refresh-Tokens-with-OAuth-2

Comment: Alright. Thanks, I will check that, but if is that way, why the error only shows up sometimes and in some accounts?

Comment: I checked it and I am request to the V1, the only thing that I am doing with V2 is the OAuth.

Comment: check my edit. i have added some information about the refreshing of tokens. Apparently its only available for some partners of linkedin.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that information, but still strange the fact that I update the account and the TTL is of 2 months then after 2 days it starts returning error code 403. Thanks for all help, I return feedback as soon as I solve this.

Comment: the 403 is not what you get because of the access token. the 403 is a result of you not being a linkedin partner. as stated above you can only access the V2 API when you are a linkedin partner. calling upon the refresh of the token is a V2 request.

Comment: I got it, but I'm using the V1 to request, the only thing I do with the V2 is the OAuth, but that is working fine and it returns 2 months TTL.
I think OAuth V1 doesn't exist, they deprecated it.
The refresh token should only be needed after 2 months.
Am I missing something?

Comment: could you edit in the api call that you are trying to make. i tought this problem was because of the refreshing of tokens.

Comment: i am not sure what is wrong, but if you have a partnership with linkedin you should look at organization V2. it will replace the company pages.